# Run Ignite docker with custom config file

Tags: docker, ignite

I've been successfully run Ignite docker with parameter `CONFIG_URI=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/ignite/master/examples/config/example-cache.xml`.

But I want to enable persistence and create a custom config file which I want to pass instead of `CONFIG_URI`.

Is there a way to pass a CONFIG file from host with the `docker run` command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your Docker run command, you can use the -v parameter (or the equivalent in the Dockerfile) to map a local directory to that of the container.

Then you'd move your configuration file in there and set your CONFIG_URI to point to that, something like `CONFIG_URI=file:///opt/etc/ignite.xml`.

Of course you'll need to create a volume of some kind for the persistent files; you don't want to be storing them inside the container.

As [antkr notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54715164/2998), if you're using Kubernetes, you can use a config map and StatefulSets, but you'd still need to set the `CONFIG_URL` in the same way.

Comment: Thanks Stephen , mapping -v and using that in CONFIG_URI worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are going to use persistence, configure persistent volume according to following documentation:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/

Mount it to your pod and read the configuration file from the volume using the CONFIG_URI parameter.